# Expo eas IOS build error ('ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to build my managed workflow project using eas build. For android it builds without any error but for IOS I get the following error:

```
❌  (node_modules/react-native-fbsdk-next/ios/ExpoAdapterFBSDKNext/FacebookAppDelegate.swift:1:8)

> 1 | import ExpoModulesCore
    |        ^ compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
  2 | import FBSDKCoreKit
  3 | 
  4 | public class FacebookAppDelegate: ExpoAppDelegateSubscriber {


❌  (node_modules/react-native-fbsdk-next/ios/ExpoAdapterFBSDKNext/FacebookAppDelegate.swift:1:8)

> 1 | import ExpoModulesCore
    |        ^ compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
  2 | import FBSDKCoreKit
  3 | 
  4 | public class FacebookAppDelegate: ExpoAppDelegateSubscriber {
```

This is my app.json:

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "eKisállat",
    "slug": "eKisallat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/AppIcons/appIcon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/AppIcons/SplashScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#519259"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios":{
      "bundleIdentifier":"",
      "deploymentTarget": "13.0",
      "supportsTablet":false,
      "buildNumber":"1.0.0",
    },
    "android": {
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [
        "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.INTERNET"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/AppIcons/appIcon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "",
      "versionCode": 39,
      "icon": "./assets/AppIcons/appIcon.png",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "3",
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "g"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/AppIcons/playstore.png"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/AppIcons/playstore.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/AppIcons/playstore.png",
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }
      ],
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "13",
          "clientToken": "4",
          "displayName": "eKisállatkönyv"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "8"
      },
      "apiUrl": apiUrl,
      "apiKey":apiKey,
      "expoProjectID": expoProjectID,
      "facebookProdAdd": facebookProdAdd,
      "firebaseApiKey": firebaseApiKey,
      "googleWebClientID": googleWebClientID,
      "androidAdmob":androidAdmob,
      "androidRewardingAd":androidRewardingAdMob,
      "iosAdmob": iosAdmob,
      "iosRewardingAdMob":iosRewardingAdMob,
      "stripeApiUrl": stripeApiUrl,
      "stripeKey": stripeKey,
      "prod": prod,
      "prodAds": prodAds,
      "facebookLoginEnabled": facebookLoginEnabled
    }
  }
}
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.28.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "emoji-dictionary": "^1.0.11",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.8",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.3",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.5.10",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.12",
    "firebase": "^9.6.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animated-pagination-dots": "^0.1.73",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.12.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-share": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-shared-element": "0.8.4",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-navigation-shared-element": "^3.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried to manually set the IOS deployment version to 13 and install expo-modules-core, but it does not work...

What else can I try? :S

Answer (score 0):

Got to XCode and find under your project name "Pods" folder, press it and on the right you will see a list of pods installed to you project. Find FBSDKCoreKit pod, and change IOS development target to 13.0

[IOS development target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enH1G.png)

Answer (score -1):

Manually updating react-native-fbsdk-next in package.json to the latest version fixed the issue!